# Change Sublime Text 3 Bracket/Indent Rules

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, brackets, curly-braces

In Sublime Text 3, I want to change auto bracket rules.
By default, I get this

```
class  extends Parent implements Interface {

}
```

but I want this

```
class  extends Parent implements Interface 
{

}
```

how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just [create a new snippet](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html), and put it in your user package folder.

The original snippet that ships with Sublime Text is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[class ${1:${TM_FILENAME/(.*?)(\..+)/$1/}} ${2:extends ${3:Parent} }${4:implements ${5:Interface} }{
    $0
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.java</scope>
    <description>javaclass</description>
</snippet>
```

You can create a new one and move the opening parenthesis down where you want it

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[class ${1:${TM_FILENAME/(.*?)(\..+)/$1/}} ${2:extends ${3:Parent} }${4:implements ${5:Interface} }
{
    $0
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.java</scope>
    <description>javaclass</description>
</snippet>
```